# How use generic T inside a method in java?

Tags: java, android, generics

We can do this in C#:

```
private T getData<T>(Context context, String url, PostModel postModel) throws ApiException, IOException, ConnectionException {
    Response response = new CallApi<T>(Connection.getApiUrl(context))
            .Post(url, postModel);    
    if (response.code() != 200) throw new ApiException(context,response);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    T obj = gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(),
            new TypeToken<T>() {
            }.getType());
    return obj;
}
```

To call:

```
EmployeeModel model =  getData<EmployeeModel>(context, url, null);
```

As you can see we declare `T` as in method signature and inside the method, it replaced with `EmployeeModel` in `CallApi<T>` and `new TypeToken<T>` and it will return `EmployeeModel` object as the result.

In Java(Android) when I want to use this generic, I have:

```
private <T> T getData(Context context, String url, PostModel postModel){...}
```

But it returns me a `LinkedTreeMap` object and not an `EmployeeModel`! When I move < T > from method signature to the class itself result is same too.

I search the web and StackOverflow for finding this type of using but articles are just about how to cast `T` to a model or how to pass it as a parameter.

> Please consider that I don't pass `T` into a method as a parameter and I don't
>   need to cast `T` to anything. T is used as the **type** on other
>   generic methods type!

So how can I implement this method in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new TypeToken<T>() {}` wouldn't work like you want it to, because of type erasure.

You would have to pass in a `TypeToken<T>` as a parameter:

```
EmployeeModel model = getData(
    context, url, null, new TypeToken<EmployeeModel>() {});
```

changing the method signature to add the extra parameter; then:

```
T obj = gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(), typeToken);
```

Comment: Thank you, Andy. I think that it's completely right! I searched for type erasure and I got that T will convert to Object! while compiling. So it will lose its type!